# Is there a one line solution for this code

Tags: python, list

I frequently use this code to unbunch a list of lists and numbers|strings

```
def deKnot(someList):
    l = []
    for each in someList: l.extend(each) if (hasattr(each,"__iter__")) else l.append(each)
    return each
```

I was hoping I could use a syntax like...

```
def deKnot(someList): return [extend(each) if (hasattr(each,"__iter__")) else append(each) for each in someList]
```

Which doesn't work.  Is there a one line solution for this problem?

Comment: From The Zen of Python: "Explicit is better than implicit".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def deKnot(someList):
    return [e 
            for each in someList 
            for e in (each if hasattr(each, '__iter__') else [each])]
```

Turn `each` *into* an iterable and always loop; instead of `.extend()` use a nested loop here in a list comprehension.

You could use [`collections.Iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=iterable#collections.Iterable) instead of the attribute check:

```
from collections import Iterable

def deKnot(someList):
    return [e 
            for each in someList 
            for e in (each if isinstance(each, Iterable) else [each])]
```